# Adding keys and associations to existing datasets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on my first ruby on rails site, so go easy on me!

I'm building a website with the sole purpose of querying two existing datasets, so no data input is needed on the app. I have two datasets to load to the website: Locations and Train_Journeys. A location can have many train journeys. A train journey has one location.

In the raw data (pre loading to website) - Locations has an existing, populated unique ID column called locationid and the Train_Journeys table has a foreign key column location_id which references an entry in Locations.

I need to create an association in Rails so I can view a location and then see a list of associated train journeys. Most of the tutorials & questions I've found online make sense but are for creating new tables where data will be created, rather than loaded. I think what I need to do is create a custom primary key on Locations?

Below is what I have so far. It's failing at the seeding stage (for the locations table).

NoMethodError: undefined method `locationid=' for #Location:0x0000000003ec5a60

**Creating Location model**

```html
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :locations, id: false, primary_key: :locationid do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.etc.......
    end
  end
end
```

**Creating train_journey model**

```html
class CreateTrainJourneys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :train_journeys do |t|
      t.integer :location_id
      otherfields....
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Location.rb**

```html
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :train_journeys
  self.primary_key = "locationid"
    
end
```

Train_journeys.rb

```html
class TrainJourney < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :location
end
```

**Seeds code**

```html
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'locations.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
csv.each do |row|
  t = Location.new
  t.name = row['name']
  t.locationid = row['locationid']
  t.population = row['population']
  t.etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could have an issue with models. Try set the location as `belongs_to` relationship at `TrainJourney` model and in the migration do the following:

```
create_table :train_journeys do |t|
      t.integer :location_id
```

Because you are storing the location id at the TrainJourney table. So, that it's a `belongs_to`. If you were storing the key at the Location table, it'd be a `has_one` relationship